# Django Filter Queryset Model

Tags: django, django-models

How can I filter my table to only show the quotes from a project.

In order to display all quotes, I am using `{% for quote in quotes.all %}`

Now, I would like to display quote relative to a site. Which means when selecting my site_id, I`ll be able to only see the quote relative to this site_id. I could write something like

```
{% for quote in quotes.all %}
    {% if quote chantier.id %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this is wrong.

Here is my model for quote:

**models.py**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)    
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I display all quotes from this site?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Where does this `chantier` comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a url path that contains the `site_id`:

```
# app_name/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app_name import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('site/<int:site_id>/', views.quotes_of_site, name='quotes_of_site'),
    # …
]
```

in the view, you can then filter by `site_id`:

```
# app_name/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from app_name.models import Quote

def quotes_of_site(request, site_id):
    quotes = Quote.objects.filter(site_id=site_id)
    return render(request, 'name_of_template.html', {'quotes': quotes})
```

and then iterate over this `QuerySet`:

```
{% for quote in quotes %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```